# Maximum count in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a schema of players in a league which looks like the schema below.

```
Player (playerid integer, mentorid integer, leagueid integer, pay integer)
League (leagueid integer, leaguename text)
```

I am trying to find leagues that have maximum number of players and solution should consider scenario having more than one leagues that have maximum number of players Result should only have - leaguename, count of players sorted by leaguename.How do i get that?

Comment: Is this your homework you are asking people to do for you?

Comment: I have that same feeling ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with x as (
select l.leaguename, count(distinct p.playerid) as player_count 
from player p join league l on p.leagueid = l.leagueid
group by l.leaguename)
, y as (select max(player_count) player_count from x)
select x.leaguename, y.player_count
from x join y on x.player_count = y.player_count
order by x.leaguename
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
select leaguename,  player_count from League l,(
select leagueid, count(leagueid) as player_count from Player 
group by leagueid having count(leagueid) >= All (select count(leagueid) from Player group by leagueid) ) t
where l.leagueid = t.leagueid 
order by leaguename
```